# How to enable `dired-auto-revert-buffer` only for Dired buffers without inserted subdirs?

Tags: emacs, revert, dired

Enabling `global-auto-revert-mode` is a wonderful way to develop/debug with another tool. Changes made to the file on disk are mirrored back in the corresponding emacs buffer.

`dired-auto-revert-buffer` makes the same possible for dired buffers, but if reverting dired buffers is enabled, it becomes impossible to use recursive directories. They take too long to reload.

How can I enable `dired-auto-revert-buffer` for dired buffers that have run neither insertion (`dired-maybe-insert-subdir`) nor, especially, recursive insertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. Perhaps someone else will have a better idea, but as far as I can see, you will need to set `dired-auto-revert-buffer` to a function (not to `t`) that returns non-nil only when there are no inserted subdirs.

This should do the trick:

```
(setq dired-auto-revert-buffer  (lambda (_dir) (null (cdr dired-subdir-alist))))
```

But keep in mind that `dired-auto-revert-buffer` has an effect only when you "revisit" an existing Dired buffer. It is not enough, for example, to just reselect its window or make its buffer current. If you use `C-x d` to revisit it, then it will be auto-reverted if it has no inserted subdirs.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `dired-auto-revert-buffer` to a function, which is called with one parameter (the directory name). If this function returns non-nil, the dired buffer is reverted.